# How do I "wrap" a response with multiple results in Node.JS

Tags: mysql, node.js, json

I need to set a route that is capable of return data from like, 3 or 4 different tables, and I need to "format" the JSON response in a specific way. For example, in PHP, that's what I need:

```
$query1 = 'select * from bananas';
$query2= 'select * from lettuces where id_potato = id_banana';

$response = [
    'name' => $query1->name,
    'phone' => $query1->phone,
    'groups' => $query2
];
```

Note that 'groups' contains $query2 which is an array.

Here's my controller until now:

```
    module.exports = app => {
    app.get('/api/public/fotos/:login', (req,res) => {
        let login = req.params.login;

        let connection = new app.connection.connectionFactory();
        let fotosDao = new app.models.FotosDao(connection);

        fotosDao.getTimeline(login, function(error, response) {
            if(error) {
                console.log('Erro ao obter a timeline: ' + error);
                res.status(500).send(error);
            } else {
                res.status(200).send(response);
            }
        });

    });
}
```

And my DAO:

```
function FotosDao(connection) {
    this._connection = connection;
}

FotosDao.prototype.getTimeline = function(login, callback) {
    this._connection.query(`
        SELECT *
        FROM foto a
        INNER JOIN usuario b ON a.usuario_id = b.id
        WHERE b.login = ?`,
        login, callback);
}

module.exports = function() {
    return FotosDao;
}
```

I need to "rebuild" the answer with different queries results. Every help is welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create for each query you have a `Promise` and then `chain` them with `.then` or you can `nest` then one under the other via `callbacks`. Example with the promise approach:

I assume you want `getTimeline` to give you that result so:

```
FotosDao.prototype.getTimeline = (login) =>
   yourQ1().then(resultQ1 => 
     yourQ2().then(resultQ2 => 
       yourQ3().then(resultQ3 => 
          // compose your result object
          return {
            name: resultQ1,
            phone: resultQ2,
            groups: resultQ3
          }
       )
     )
   )    
}
```

A more elegant way would involve Promise.all():

```
Promise.all([yourQ1, yourQ2, yourQ3]).then(function(values) {
  composeYourResult(values);
});
```

The key here is to "promisify" your queries so you can chain/manipulate their results and handle better their async execution. Now you can do your own promise handler for mysql queries or you can use something like [promise-mysql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise-mysql) or other packages I am sure there should be plenty.